# How to upgrade wordpress version?

Tags: upgrade

My website is running on WordPress version `4.9.8`.

When I go to `<mysite>/wp-admin/update-core.php`, it says,

> You have the latest version of WordPress. Future security updates will
>   be applied automatically.

**I want to upgrade my site to version 5.0.x**

How can I do that?

Comment: you might have auto update disabled?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have already tried to update WordPress but the process broked. 
So to resolve your problem you can go with the following:
1. Click to "Re-install now" button and install WordPress again.
2. Click to " Download" and install the WordPress manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Latest WordPress manually, don't delete your wp-content folder and unzip the file from https://wordpress.iorg/latest.zip.

Check this Article https://codex.wordpress.org/Upgrading_WordPress#Manual_Update

Thanks !!!